# Replicate distplot with rug without histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

As I go through online tutorials and\or articles in general, when I encounter a plot that uses
the Seaborn distplot plot I re-create it using either histplot or displot.

I do this because distplot is deprecated and I want to re-write the code using newer standards.

I am going through this article:  https://www.kite.com/blog/python/data-analysis-visualization-python/

and there is a section using distplot whose output I cannot replicate.

This is the section of code that I am trying to replicate:

```
col_names = ['StrengthFactor', 'PriceReg', 'ReleaseYear', 'ItemCount', 'LowUserPrice', 'LowNetPrice']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(col_names), figsize=(8, 40))
for i, col_val in enumerate(col_names):
    x = sales_data_hist[col_val][:1000]
    sns.distplot(x, ax=ax[i], rug=True, hist=False)
    outliers = x[percentile_based_outlier(x)]
    ax[i].plot(outliers, np.zeros_like(outliers), 'ro', clip_on=False)

    ax[i].set_title('Outlier detection - {}'.format(col_val), fontsize=10)
    ax[i].set_xlabel(col_val, fontsize=8)

plt.show()
```

Both the distplot itself and the axis variable are no longer used.  The code, for now, runs.

In a nutshell, all I am trying to do is replicate the **exact output** of the code above (rug plot, the red dots representing the removed values, etc.) without using deprecated code.

I have tried various combinations of displot and histplot but I have been unable to get the exact same output any other way.

Comment: It seems like `displot` should be able to replicate this. To save others duplicating your efforts, what have you already tried, and how is it different from the original output?

Comment: The closest I have come is this:    ```sns.displot(x, ax=ax[i], rug=True)```  I get the rug, but it's a histogram, not a kde plot, which I don't understand at all since I am using displot.  The red dots representing the removed values are gone, and I can't figure out how to get rid of the axis option without completely breaking the output. Histplot has no rug option.

Comment: Using the above line, I get these warnings (and I do not replicate the code posted in my question): ```C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py:2164: UserWarning: `displot` is a figure-level function and does not accept the ax= paramter. You may wish to try histplot.
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)```

Comment: Yes, the documentation states `displot` is a figure level function, not an axes level function, so you can't tell it which axes to plot on. I believe you could, instead, use `kdeplot()` and `rugplot()` to get the result you want (I think that is what `displot` is doing under the hood anyway). Additionally, if you want to keep using `displot`, you can use `kind='kde'` to get a kde plot rather than a histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sns.kdeplot()` function shows the kde curve available in `distplot`. (In fact, `distplot` just calls `kdeplot` internally). Similarly, there is `sns.rugplot()` to show the rug.

Here is an example with the easier to replicate iris dataset:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

def percentile_based_outlier(data, threshold=95):
    diff = (100 - threshold) / 2
    minval, maxval = np.percentile(data, [diff, 100 - diff])
    return (data < minval) | (data > maxval)

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
col_names = [col for col in iris.columns if iris[col].dtype == 'float64']  # the numerical columns
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(col_names), figsize=(5, 12))
for ax, col_val in zip(axs, col_names):
    x = iris[col_val]
    sns.kdeplot(x, ax=ax)
    sns.rugplot(x, ax=ax, color='C0')
    outliers = x[percentile_based_outlier(x)]
    ax.plot(outliers, np.zeros_like(outliers), 'ro', clip_on=False)

    ax.set_title(f'Outlier detection - {col_val}', fontsize=10)
    ax.set_xlabel('')  # ax[i].set_xlabel(col_val, fontsize=8)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: emulating sns.displot(hist=False, rug=True)]

To use `displot`, the dataframe can be converted to ["long form"](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) via `pd.melt()`. The outliers can be added via a custom function called by `g.map_dataframe(...)`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

def percentile_based_outlier(data, threshold=95):
    diff = (100 - threshold) / 2
    minval, maxval = np.percentile(data, [diff, 100 - diff])
    return (data < minval) | (data > maxval)

def show_outliers(data, color):
    col_name = data['variable'].values[0]
    x = data['value'].to_numpy()
    outliers = x[percentile_based_outlier(x)]
    plt.plot(outliers, np.zeros_like(outliers), 'ro', clip_on=False)
    plt.xlabel('')

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
col_names = [col for col in iris.columns if iris[col].dtype == 'float64']  # the numerical columns
iris_long = iris.melt(value_vars=col_names)
g = sns.displot(data=iris_long, x='value', kind='kde', rug=True, row='variable',
                height=2.2, aspect=3,
                facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
g.map_dataframe(show_outliers)
```

[image: displot with outliers]